# Get selected itemValue of p:selectOneMenu in listener method?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primtefaces 3.5 and below code to poplulate p:selectOneMenu. On selecting an item, I want to know the value of selected itemValue i.e. userStar.userStarId.
Have tried using f:setPropertyActionListener or f:attribute or passing the value in listener method, but no luck.

Thanks for your time and help.

```
<p:selectOneMenu editable="true" style="width:300px" value="#{starBean.newStarName}"> 
       <f:selectItems value="#{starBean.userStarList}" var="userStar" itemLabel="#{userStar.starName}" itemValue="#{userStar.userStarId}" />

     <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{starBean.changeValueListener}" process="@this" partialSubmit="true">

     </p:ajax>

 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: You need to implement a custom converter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a converter, but it keeps returning selected value as "#{starBean.newStarName}", and not the expected value from, "#{userStar.userStarId}". Please let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`<p:selectOneMenu editable="true" style="width:300px" value="#{starBean.newStarName}">`

to

```
<p:selectOneMenu editable="true" style="width:300px" value="#{starBean.userStarId}">
```

`p:selectOneMenu` value is the selected value here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using Custom Converter, you can put all your pojo in Map and load that in to `p:selectOneMenu` and once you get the selected pojo using `Map.get(K)`.

Initialization:

```
Map<String,UserStar> userStarMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,UserStar>();
UserStar user1 = new UserStar(...);
userStrMap.put(user1.userStarId, user1);
...
...
...
```

Facelt:

```
<p:selectOneMenu editable="true" style="width:300px" value="#{starBean.newStarName}"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{starBean.userStarMap.values()}" 
                  var="userStar" itemLabel="#{userStar.starName}" itemValue="#{userStar.userStarId}" />

     <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{starBean.changeValueListener}" process="@this" partialSubmit="true">

     </p:ajax>

 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Listener:

```
public void changeValueListener(){
    UserStar selectedUser = userStarMap.get(newStarName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kishor. But the issue is starBean.newStarName is not same as user1.userStarId. So, the key when storing in Map is user1.userStarId, and when we use starBean.newStarName to get the value from Map, it won't work.